# Perl oneliner to match exact word in a path on many different values with special characters

Tags: linux, perl, bash, ksh, ls

How do I match exactly the $TARGET_NAME value from **find /tmp -type l -exec ls -l** output?

```
 $ find /tmp -type l -exec ls -l 2>/dev/null {} +
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  24 Mar 18 12:41 /tmp/test/link -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  43 Mar 18 12:41 /tmp/test/link1 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  68 Mar 18 12:41 /tmp/test/link2 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 100 Mar 18 12:42 /tmp/test/link3 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy*Printed
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  92 Mar 18 12:42 /tmp/test/link4 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files@emails.dummy
```

Examples of values

```
 TARGET_NAME=Upload.CM@.www.com
 TARGET_NAME=Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
 TARGET_NAME=List.files.emails.dummy*Printed
```

**Target:** print: "link name"  and "PATH" (last field ) only if $TARGET_NAME 
match exactly the word in the last field.

Example (when we want to match exact - while **TARGET_NAME**=Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
then):

The results will display as the following

```
/tmp/test/link2 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
/tmp/test/link3 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy*Printed
/tmp/test/link4 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files@emails.dummy
```

There are a few conditions:

1) Need to match only the last field (from `ls -l` output)

Example

```
      /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com
```

2) $TARGET_NAME value should match the whole word

Example of full match ( while **TARGET_NAME=Upload.CM@.www.com** ):

```
    /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com
```

Example of a non-full match:

```
    /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.c
```

3) A backslash ("/") must exist on the left side of $TARGET_NAME, and a backslash or the end of the string must be found on the right of $TARGET_NAME.

4) Need to escape special characters as:   " / " , " **@** " . "  *****  " , etc

5) The code will be part of a ksh script (and could beimplemented by a Perl oneliner or [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) or ksh etc .. )

**Example**

```
   find /tmp -type l -exec ls -l 2>/dev/null {} + | < Perl one liner .............. >
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ?

Comment: Don't parse ls output, even when it comes from `find`

Comment: @Sputnick I don’t have other alternative ( I need to verify all PATH that links are pointed to )

Comment: Yes, you have by example : `find -type l -printf '%l\n'` it's a better start.

Comment: @Sputnick thx , this is new info for me

Comment: @Sputnick how to print also the link name before the last field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in response to your last question (since deleted), parsing `ls` output is very suboptimal. `readlink` can be used instead.

```
find /tmp -type l -exec \
   perl -e'
      my $TARGET_NAME = shift;
      for (@ARGV) {
         my $p = readlink($_);
         $p =~ m{(?:^|/)\Q$TARGET_NAME\E(?:/|\z)}
            or next;
         print("$_\t$p\n");
      }
   ' "$TARGET_NAME" {} \;
```

Or more efficiently,

```
perl -MFile::Find::Rule -e'
   my ($TARGET_NAME, $BASE) = @ARGV;
   for (File::Find::Rule->symlink->in($BASE)) {
      my $p = readlink($_);
      $p =~ m{(?:^|/)\Q$TARGET_NAME\E(?:/|\z)}
         or next;
      print("$_\t$p\n");
   }
' "$TARGET_NAME" /tmp
```

As requested, this will match

```
TARGET_NAME
TARGET_NAME/
TARGET_NAME/x
.../TARGET_NAME
.../TARGET_NAME/
.../TARGET_NAME/x
```

but not

```
TARGET_NAMEx/...
.../TARGET_NAMEx
.../TARGET_NAMEx/...
xTARGET_NAME/...
.../xTARGET_NAME
.../xTARGET_NAME/...
```

---

Note: Change `find ... -exec ... \;` to `find ... -exec ... +` if your `find` supports it.

Comment: ( this remark is the same remark that I told to Olaf ) if I set TARGET_NAME=Collect_tests then I expected to see 6 matched lines "see my queastion details" so ... ( for all the links link,link1,link2,link3,link4,link5 ) the code print only link Collect_tests remark - the reason that I want to print all lines that matches the $TARGET_NAME , because I need later to re-create new links

Comment: second problem the code not work on solaris 10 ... cant understand this ? ( no any output from code )

Comment: ug, your post says exactly the opposite of your first comment. I have fixed your question and adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: And I can't fix your Solaris problem if you don't tell me what the problem is. (`find` doesn't produce anything? `@ARGV` empty? Regex doesn't match?) Put some effort already!

Comment: did you know why your first code not fit for solaris 10 ? ( its run only on linux )

Comment: No, which is why I asked you to find out. I really shouldn't have to tell you!

Comment: ok I will try to find out ( but Perl syntax should be the same on the same OS – so its very diffvuilt to understand why ? )

Comment: I'm confused. Is this a syntax error or do you get no output?

Comment: Adding `-w` or adding `or die $!` to `readlink` might shed some light

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26451/discussion-between-eytan-and-ikegami)

Comment: about perl version in solaris - This is perl, v5.8.7 built for sun4-solaris-thread-multi , and perl version on linux - This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i686-linux

Comment: can we do something else in order to find the problem - why on solaris the first code not print anything ?

Comment: @Eytan, Else? You didn't say what you tried. I told you 4 things to check. So which one doesn't give what you want?

Comment: I find the problem - the "/" before "\Q" , so if I remove the back slash then its work on both OS

Comment: not clear for me why you add the "/" before \Q ? , can you update your answer and remove the "/" ,

Comment: No, I can't remove the `/`, cause then it would match `.../xTARGET_NAME/...`. If it doesn't match, it's because you've mistated your question (again). I can only answer the question you actually post. If your question is wrong, start by fixing it.

Comment: but this is the reson that its not work on solaris , as you know on linux its work but not on solaris , so I remove the "/" and then its work on solaris ... so what you think .. can you provide other alternative ? in place the "/" - ok so you now know the problem

Comment: @Eytan, Alternative? It works perfectly well for the question you asked.

Comment: Not so. It works perfectly fine on Solaris for the links you said it's suppose to work on. Again, I can only answer the question you actually ask. I'm tired of guessing because you don't want to do any work.

Comment: on my solaris it not work , I have solaris 10 , did you check it on solaris OS ? , which perl version you have on solaris ?

Comment: I don't have access to Solaris. I don't need it to have access to Solaris to know IT WORKS PERFECTLY FINE ON SOLARIS FOR THE LINKS YOU SAID IT'S SUPPOSE TO WORK ON. If it doesn't work on Solaris, then YOUR QUESTION IS WRONG.

Comment: OK , I find the problem , you right  - sometimes the name of the dir/file not start with "/" , for example link1 -> Collect_tests , so in this case it will not match , what is right - the code need to support if "/" exist or if not before dir/file , can you update your solution according to what I said and I will add remark about this in my question ?

Comment: Ok, and what do you think would be needed to match "start of string or `/`" instead of just "`/`"?

Comment: Ho its simple - space , the rule will be space|/

Comment: huh, no, that won't match the start of the string. `^` will, so it's `(?:^|/)`! Adjusted code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following links

```
$ cd /tmp

$ ls -l link* | sed -e 's/^.*\(link\)/\1/'
link -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests
link1 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com
link2 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
link3 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy*Printed
link4 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy
link5 -> /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/
```

use the File::Find module as in

```
$ TARGET_NAME='Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com' perl -MFile::Find -le 'find sub {
   -l && defined($dst = readlink $_) &&
   index($dst, $ENV{TARGET_NAME}) >= 0 &&
   print "$File::Find::name $dst" }, @ARGV' /tmp
/tmp/link2 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
/tmp/link3 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy*Printed
/tmp/link4 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy
```

That’s really unwieldy as a one-liner. As a separate command, it becomes

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

die "Usage: $0 root-dir ..\n" unless @ARGV;
die "$0: TARGET_NAME is not defined\n" unless exists $ENV{TARGET_NAME};

sub print_matching_target_name {
  return unless -l && defined(my $dst = readlink $_);
  print "$File::Find::name $dst\n" if index($dst, $ENV{TARGET_NAME}) >= 0;
}

find \&print_matching_target_name, @ARGV;
```

Sample output:

```
$ find-target
Usage: find-target root-dir ..

$ find-target /tmp
find-target: TARGET_NAME is not defined

$ TARGET_NAME=Upload.CM@.www.com ./find-target /tmp
/tmp/link2 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com
/tmp/link3 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy*Printed
/tmp/link4 /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com/List.files.emails.dummy
```

Comment: is it possible to print also the link file before "TARGET_NAME" , for example: /tmp/link TARGET_NAME=Upload.CM@.www.com

Comment: any why the target of my question is to verify if $TARGET_NAME value matched in the PATH ( of the last field ) , I not want only to print the basename of each PATH - the target is to match the $TARGET_NAME with the output ( last field PATH )

Comment: @Eytan I understand what you are looking for now. See updated answer.

Comment: thanx , one more question if I want also to print the full $TARGET_NAME , I need to set that:   print "$File::Find::name $b"  $ENV{TARGET_NAME}}, @ARGV' /tmp  ???

Comment: example what I need: /tmp/test/link2 Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com     /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com

Comment: @Eytan The full name (the destination of the symlink) is the result of calling `readlink`, so you would need to save the return value in a variable and print that.

Comment: is it possible to update your answer with that , because I not success to update the liner perl line

Comment: I noticed about little problem
if I set TARGET_NAME=Collect_tests
then I expected to see 6 matched lines ( for all the links link,link1,link2,link3,link4,link5 )
the code print only link Collect_tests
remark - the reason that I want to print all lines that matches the $TARGET_NAME , because I need later to re-create new links

Comment: you can also see the update question - I add new example near the line "The results will display as the following"

Comment: your code is exelent ( on both OS linux & solaris ) , But I still need your help about the two last three comments ..

Comment: Greg last question,  I need to defined another value as: export  NEW_NAME=’Upload_NEW.Shema.com' ,  and I want to print it in the three field ( last field )

Comment: example: /tmp/link2     /usr/admin/Collect_tests/Upload.CM@.www.com/Upload_Shema@@@.DATA.com    Upload_NEW.Shema.com

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
    printf "TARGET_NAME=%q\n" "$file"
done < <(find /tmp -type l -printf '%l\n')
```

The result is backslashed, for example:

```
TARGET_NAME=/tmp/foo/List.files.emails.dummy\*Printed
```

Comment: Why not `printf 'TARGET_NAME=%q\n' "$file"`?  Also, why two '-printf '%l\n' options to `find`?

Comment: @Sputnick why its print "\" before "*" , output should the same as the directory/file name

Comment: Post edited accordingly. Removed a typo and added an improvement

Comment: @Eytan, this is for the requirement : `4) need to escape special characters as: " / " , " @ " . " * " , etc`

Comment: Note that if the link target contains any characters like an embedded newline, the output of `printf '%q'` will contain the bash-like `$'foo\nbar'`.  The requirements do not specify how to handle this case.

Comment: In more than 10 years of Unixes, I never seen a file with newline. (I know this is feasible)

Comment: @sputnick okay...I used the newline as an example, but _any_ nonprintable character suffers from this same problem.  Have you ever seen UTF-8 encoded file names used?

Answer (score 0):

Since the target may or may not be the same as the part to be returned, seems easiest to make two separate regex calls (may also help if this should be generalized):

```
perl -ne 'print "$1" if (m#Upload.CM@.www.com# && m#([^/]+)\s*$#);'
```

In other words, find the target phrase then get the last component of find (that which doesn't contain a "/"). When both conditions are met, print the text captured in parentheses.

Regarding special characters:
If "#" is replaced with the more traditional "/", you'd need to escape the one I wrote as "/", Otherwise, the "@" shouldn't cause you trouble. Of course, if it does on your system, just escape them with "\".